# Import UV Layout in Blender 3.2

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

in the official Docs it says that I could import a UV Layout that I have previously exported (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/mesh_uv_layout.html)
However I struggle with that...
First, I can not export the layout in .tga format
Second, when I try to open the image as described, .svg and .eps files are not considered valid

What I need to do is consistently unwrap a certain topology: It will always be the same mesh (generated externally) with same stats, but when using the same config for the Smart UV Unwrap, it creates slightly different layout each time I try. But in order to have one consistent texture, I need to transfer one standardized UV Map onto the mesh.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I can not export the layout in .tga format

You can't, it's either PNG, SVG or EPS:

[image: formats]

> when I try to open the image as described, .svg and .eps files are not considered valid

I can open them fine on Glimpse/Gimp, so they are definitely valid. But figuring out what's going on with a different software would be out of subject on this website.

If you are trying to open them in Blender, I don't think Blender support these formats to begin with.

As explained in the addon's manual:

> Using your favorite image painting program, you could use an exported UV layout to create a texture.

This is really meant to help you paint your textures on your UVs externally. PNGs can work in Blender, but not vectorial picture formats.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I really appreciate you trying to help :) Yeah, but in the docs it says "Then save your changes, and back in Blender, use the Image ‣ Open to load it as your UV image for the mesh in Edit Mode for the desired (and active) UV map." So how can I import the .svg and .eps when Blender doesn't support these formats? Opening the image in .png just loads the texture and doesn't apply the UV grid, it still remains the previous one in Blender...

Comment: Either you want to paint in Blender and you use the PNG export, or you want to paint elsewhere and use either of the three format as you like. And yes, it's just an image. It doesn't alter the UV themselves, it's just a guide for you when painting.

Comment: Yes, and thats the problem. I want to create an addon that loads this particular UV Map onto any asset with matching topology. Therefore I want to store the UV Information somewhere where Blender can access it across multiple projects

Comment: You should have started from there maybe x) No need for an addon, just Select your object to copy to, then Shift select the object with the UV to copy, and press Ctrl L > Copy UV Maps

Comment: [Copy UV Maps — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/link_transfer/copy_uvmaps.html)

Comment: Thanks again, but this requires to have one object with the actual UV Map loaded into Blender. I just want to apply the UV Map - otherwise I have to load the object each and every time manually into the scene. So save the data that generates the UV Grid in question and just use it on any object with matching topology. No need to load another mesh into the scene. The way I have read the docs linked in OP, it should be possible with the function "Export UV Grid"

Comment: All the "Export UV Layout" does is exporting a picture of the UVs. Nothing more. If you want to program an addon that somehow re-creates UVs from that picture, go for it. But that isn't an existing feature.

Comment: You need to consistently unwrap a certain topology, which will always be the same mesh - what changes in the mesh? Is it only deformation but the same topology? Please edit your question as it is not very clear and provide an example about your process in the form of screenshots. You need a reference mesh having the desired UV map data and a target mesh preferably having the same topology to receive the data.